# Showing some errors while I'm trying to boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, bios

```
0.0320561 with/cpa U Contside TXT) disabled by 8103 0.0420621 xer: SGX disabled by BIS.
5.5612361 ata1.00: enception ask 0x9 ct 0x20000 SErr the action 0x0
5.5613601 ata1.00: leg stat 0x1000000
5.5611251 stel.00: fellet consand: READ TOMA QUEUED
5.561531 ata1.00: ent so 18:88:00 02:00-01:00:00:00:00/-10 tag 17 neg dna 250 in 55615631 ees 41/40:00 96 02:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 ask 9 tuntia error) F
5:5617101 ata1.00: status 1 DRDY ERR) 5.5610031 ata1.00: rene (IMC) 55632211 update request: 0 error, dou pla, sector 656 ve x-HED) Flags 0700 ply my 14 pria class 67091431 ACP Error handler for Begion C1 (OR6000113) (SustenCH (22107yine-130)
67053103 CF1 Error Regis Sisters (10-5) has no handler (20210730/fldt-261) 2004 ACE1 Error: Morting method 10 EST due to previuus error (AL_MIT_EXIST (262107X/psparse_5291, 4.706221 (CFL Error Aborting mition 28. PC10 1PCB SC, 12 due to previs error (NOT KIT
13.1292401 ata1.00 exception Enash Out Dect 08 Sker to action l 1312990 stal 00 failed Linen WERD FPORA QUEUED
13.106051 stat E0 008 18:58:00/00:00:00:00.88-40 tag 3 my da 4096 in 13 129585 res 11-10 00:00:03:00/00:00:00:00/00 East 0409 do 6
13, 129099) stat.00 states DRDY ERD)
13, 1230051 ata1.00) error(UK)
13.118301 Tk update request 10 errade, sector 056 up OsO ADX Flags a plage seg p
23:1129773 Buffer Le were go due, logical black 107, page
2020720pare
B
02
W
R
Y
D
H
K
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using and this does not look like errors in English.

Comment: Please see the picture i have attached with the question. Btw I'm using 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: I see a media failure in that screen shot. Disk failure.

Comment: Stop using the disk. Get a new one and reinstall your OS, also get a suitable USB enclosure for the current disk. Install ` TestDisk` and run it on the old disk to attempt get back any or all data.

Comment: Yeah that's a disk showing failures and in my experience drive not ready errors as well as progressively or associated longer times is hinting at imminent possible drive failure. Hoe old is the drive? Either way backup things while you can before the day you turn on the your computer and get the dreaded 'Drive Not Found' error.